# Android, How to make a basic Handler Static

Tags: android, multithreading, static, handler

I am new to Android programming and only have a very basic knowledge of it. I am trying to understand basic multithreading.

I have followed a tutorial for creating a basic thread and displaying a progressDialog which simply adds 500 records to a database when the button is clicked.

```
    public void btnAddClick(View v) {
    // Create progress dialog to show status
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Loading", "Updating database...");

    h = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    };

    // Create a new thread
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.run();
            // Time consuming task here
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
                UpdateDB();
                h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    .start();
    //UpdateDB();
}
```

With this code i get a warning within the IDE: This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur.

I Have 2 more buttons View and Clear, i use the same code for each of them and just UpdateDB(); Becomes ViewDB(); and ClearDB();

The code compiles and the AddClick works perfectly, but if i try and use ViewClick or ClearClick then my application crashes, on View sometimes the dialog displays for a few seconds then my application is crashing.

Is that caused by a resource leak? and can somebody please show me an example of how to make the Handler static so i avoid issues while using it.

The Full source code for the activity is here:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected ProgressDialog dialog;
    protected Handler h;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    DBAdapter myDb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkDataBase();    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();  
        closeDB();
    }

    private void openDB() {
        myDb = new DBAdapter(this);
        myDb.open();
    }

    private void closeDB() {
        myDb.close();
    }

    private void displayText(String message) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDisplay);
        textView.setText(message);
    }

    public void btnAddClick(View v) {
        // Create progress dialog to show status
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait", "Updating database...");

        h = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        };

        // Create a new thread
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.run();
                // Time consuming task here
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                    UpdateDB();
                    h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        .start();
        //UpdateDB();
    }

    public void btnClearClick(View v) {
        // Create progress dialog to show status
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait", "Deleting database...");

        h = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        };

        // Create a new thread
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.run();
                // Time consuming task here
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                    ClearDB();
                    h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        .start();
    }

    public void btnViewClick(View v) {
        // Create progress dialog to show status
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait", "Displaying records...");

        h = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        };

        // Create a new thread
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.run();
                // Time consuming task here
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                    ViewDB();
                    h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        .start();

    }

    // Display full database inside TextView
    private void displayRecordSet(Cursor cursor) {
        String message = "";
        // populate the message from the cursor

        // Reset cursor to start, checking to see if there's data:
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                // Process the data:
                int id = cursor.getInt(DBAdapter.COL_ROWID);
                String make = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_MAKE);
                String model = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_MODEL);
                String year = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_YEAR);
                String tyreSize = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_TYRESIZE);
                String front = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_FRONT);
                String rear = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_REAR);

                // Append data to the message:
                message += "id=" + id
                           +", make=" + make
                           +", model=" + model
                           +", year=" + year
                           +", tyreSize=" + tyreSize
                           +", front=" + front
                           +", rear=" + rear
                           +"\n";
            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // Close the cursor to avoid a resource leak.
        cursor.close();

        displayText(message);
    }

    // Checks database file exists during OnCreate();
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String DB_FULL_PATH = "/data/data/com.digitak.mytyrepressure/databases/myDb";
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_FULL_PATH , null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            checkDB.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database doesn't exist yet.
            System.out.println("Database Doesnt Exist...Creating");
            openDB();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    // Adds 500 Records to the database for testing purposes
    public void UpdateDB() {
        int x = 0;
        while (x < 500) {
            myDb.insertRow("Ford", "KA", "1996-2003", "155/70R13", "31", "26");
            x++;
        }
    }

    public void ViewDB() {
        Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();
        displayRecordSet(cursor);
    }

    public void ClearDB() {
        myDb.deleteAll();
    }

}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it didn't happen because of leak but why it happened it would be easier to say if we see catlog..

Side note..  WTH is Thread.sleep(1) for???

Side note 2: You shouldn't use threads here at all.. If you need to do task in background in general there is AsyncTask class. Specifically for DB transaction, there are even better content provider and Loader concepts..

Hope I help a bit so you can go in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Add this argument when creating *Handler*: `Looper.getMainLooper()`

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){...
}
```

This should remove the warning